# Is there a standard way of associating an image with a biblatex entry?

Tags: biblatex, graphics, csv

I have a list of articles in a `bib` file and would like to associate a different  image with each entry.  Is there any standard way of doing this?

To put this into context, in order to import the data into a content management system, I subsequently want to use Python to parse the `bib` file, convert it to a `CSV` format and add the name of the image to each line of the `CSV` file.  It would be nice to have the image data in the `bib` file, since otherwise I would need a second file which contains a mapping between the article IDs and the corresponding image file names.

Comment: unknown keys are ignored by bibtex so you can add image=....  or whatever key you want with the filenames to your bib file

Comment: Ah, good point.  The Python module ```bibtexparse``` I'm using has a flag ```ignore_nonstandard_types``` for entries.  I'll have to see whether it is opinionated about the fields in a standard type.  Otherwise I'll have to recycle an existing field as suggested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/622199/175835

Comment: Note that there is a difference between entry type and field here. A parser that only understand a hard-coded list of fields would probably be problematic. A parser that ignores unknown entry types (or can be set up to do that) much less so. ...

Comment: ... There is only a fairly weak notion of 'standard' fields or entry types in `.bib` files. The language in which BibTeX styles are written allows style authors to define all kinds of entry types and fields. Unknown fields are ignored and one can define fallbacks for unknown entry types. The BibTeX base styles (`plain.bst` and friends) that come with BibTeX define a number of fields and types and most other styles build on this data model. But styles authors are free to add more fields or ignore certain fields. ...

Comment: ... The set of fields defined by the core BibTeX styles certainly does not have a field for an image (because that is not a usual requirement for bibliographies - much less so in the late eighties), so in that sense there is no standard way to do this. But since the set of fields usable in an entry is supposed to be extensible I would like to argue that the way suggested by David above of adding a new field `image` (or what have you) is the recommended way of going about this.

Answer (score 1):

If you produced a stub MWE I would extend that, but since you have not I will simply say that (for a bib used in BibLatex here):

Assuming you actually want the image to show up in the printed bibliography...

There is nothing stopping you from subverting an existing bib field - for example note or addendum - to include an image for example (a @MISC entry here but could be anything else):

```
@MISC{test16,
  author = {Me Myself},
  title = {A Title},
  date = {1999-05-19},
  url = {https://www.google.co.uk},
  urldate = {2010-09-19},
  subtitle = {This is the subtitle field},
  addendum = {\includegraphics[width=40mm]{testfig.png}},
}
```

If you wanted you could have some sort of macro in your main source that simplifies and refines the layout for example

```
\newcommand{\bibandpic}[4]{
\begin{minipage}[t]{#1\textwidth}#3\end{minipage}%
\hfill\includegraphics[width=#2\linewidth,valign=t]{#4}\newline
}
```

and then have a bib entry something like:

```
@Misc{test17,
  note         = {\bibandpic{0.79}{0.19}{Some sort of caption text to go next to image}{image.png}},
}
```

Comment: Currently my focus is on getting the data into the CMS, but having a printed bibliography with the images would also be handy. As the bibliography is quite long I would probably skip thinking up captions for them all.  Or is there any way of referencing another of the bib entry fields to use a the caption?

Comment: You don't need a caption at all - the macro is just an example of the sort of thing you could do.

Comment: Yes, the example is very instructive.  I realise that I don't need a caption, but if I could automatically insert the contents of, say, the author and year fields, as a comment, that would be rather elegant.

Comment: `xref`, `crossref` and `xdata` fields in biblatex are designed exactly for what you want: they have different levels of inheritance.

Comment: I don't think I need inheritance as there is just a 1-to-1 relationship between articles and images.  So would one idea be to define an ```@XData``` entry with the file name of the image for each image and then reference that in the corresponding article entry via ```xdata```?