# Bibliography with QR codes to the right of the entry?

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have managed to get `biblatex` and `biber` to include a QR code for bibliography items that contain a URL -- like so:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book { texlive-home,
  shorthand = {TLD1},
  author    = {The TeX User Group},
  title     = {TeX Live},
  note      = {some text to make the entry appear more voluminous},
  url       = {https://www.tug.org/texlive/}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{biblatex.cfg}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [book]
  {url}{\par{\scriptsize\ttfamily\url{#1}}\par\vspace{1.5mm}\qrcode{#1}\vspace{3mm}}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\appto{\biburlsetup}{\renewcommand*{\UrlFont}{\scriptsize\ttfamily}}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This works, but it wastes a lot of space:

[image: example above]

I would like for the QR code to be positioned to the right of the entry like so:

[image: what I actually want, badly cut and glued together]

Within a document I would probably use a simple `tabular` environment for this, but all I've managed to create are impressive error messages. Could anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Maybe the package `hvqrurl` is what you are looking for?

Comment: See my previous answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622192/is-there-a-standard-way-of-associating-an-image-with-a-biblatex-entry/622199#622199

It's easy to get images and other material into entries, and positioned

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn In this case, I want to change the layout of the entire entry - wrap the existing text (which I'm mostly happy with) and place another element next to it. The fact that the thing I want to place to the right us a graphical element is mostly a coincidence. Unless I'm missing something entirely, your answer does not go into layouting a bib entry...?

Comment: @schtandard Interesting idea, but if possible, I'd like to stay within the main text boundaries. The actual page is relatively narrow, and I can't easily increase the margin width to make the QR codes usable. Also, if the entries get too short, the QR codes will start to overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer a real tabular bibliography, you may want to have a look at `biblatex-ext-tabular` from my [`biblatex-ext` bundle](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext).

The advantage of using a table is that you'll always have enough space for the QR code.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex-ext-tabular}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{%
  >{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{qrurl}{%
  \raisebox{\dimeval{-\height+\ht\strutbox}}{\qrcode{#1}}}

\defbibtabular{bibtabular}
  {\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}%
   \setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}%
   \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}%
   \begin{longtable}{%
   @{}
   L{\labelalphawidth}
   L{\dimexpr0.7\textwidth-0.7\labelalphawidth\relax}
   L{\dimexpr0.3\textwidth-0.3\labelalphawidth\relax}
   @{}}}
  {\end{longtable}}
  {\anchorlang{%
     \printtext[labelalphawidth]{%
       \printfield{labelprefix}%
       \printfield{labelalpha}%
       \printfield{extraalpha}}} &
   \driver{} &
   \plain{\printfield[qrurl]{url}}
    \\}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{texlive-home,
  shorthand = {TLD1},
  author    = {The TeX User Group},
  title     = {TeX Live},
  note      = {some text to make the entry appear more voluminous},
  url       = {https://www.tug.org/texlive/}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{texlive-home,sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum,ctan}
\printbibtabular
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography with QR code in left column.]

Comment: I decided to use this approach because most of my entries have a URL, but little other text, so I appreciate the "auto-spacing" very much.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to adapt the sizes, but something like this should work.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,url=false]{biblatex}
\appto{\biburlsetup}{\renewcommand*{\UrlFont}{\scriptsize\ttfamily}}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  {qrurl}{\qrcode{#1}}

\renewbibmacro{begentry}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace*{\linewidth}\quad\raisebox{\dimeval{-\height+\ht\strutbox}}[0pt][0pt]{\printfield[qrurl]{url}}}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelalphawidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelalpha}%
        \printfield{extraalpha}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelalphawidth}%
      \setlength\rightmargin{3cm}% %<------- adapt ...
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}    
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\cite{ctan,doody}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]