# \dimeval for pdflatex?

Tags: calculations, dimension-expressions, xfp

I'm using `pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)`.
In a [recent question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/652021/bibliography-with-qr-codes-to-the-right-of-the-entry), I have been provided with two excellent answers that unfortunately both make use of `\dimeval`. This command is unknown in my version of `pdflatex`; adding the `xfp` package does not help. Is there a drop-in replacement for this command that I could use?

Comment: `\dimeval` exist for pdflatex too, but you need a current latex version, in older latex you can use `\dimexpr -\height+\ht\strutbox\relax` instead.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `pdflatex --version` tells me I'm using `pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)` - that does not appear to be recent enough?

Comment: it is the version of latex that matters, not the version of pdftex. It is possible to dump a format as in mylatex using lualatex, just a bit harder to set up as you can not dump Lua state or OpenType fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `\dimeval` in the kernel you need the June 2022 release of LaTeX. For earlier versions (at least 2019, I guess) you can add

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_if_exist:NF \dimeval { \cs_set_eq:NN \dimeval \dim_eval:n }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

TeX Live 2022/Debian is not recent enough, I'm afraid, because it only has the October 2021 release of LaTeX. Maybe it will be updated, but I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: To get `\dimeval`, which file exactly should date June 2022 or later? Is it latex.ltx or something else? (I use Debian, and in the meantime the packages there might have probably been updated. I simply want to know or to deduce which package to update.)

Comment: @AlbertNash Check the release date of LaTeX you see in the log file.

Comment: Are you referring to a string such as `LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1`?  Where is this string generated, i.e., by which executables and data files?

Comment: @AlbertNash It's saved at format creation. But you can find it also in `latex.ltx`, look for `\fmtversion`.